# Android Application not releasing memory and not closed

Tags: java, android

I coded program when i press "back", finish application and stop all service.

But after finish, Android studio says application is not closed, and profiler still say app is not closed and using memory.

How can I release all memory and close application without `System.exit(0)` and `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())`?

Here's code when I used at test.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
  finishAndRemoveTask();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
  // Stopping notification listener service
  stopService(serv);
  // Removing notification
  ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICES)).cancel(0);
  System.out.println("Goodbye, Cruel world.");
}
```

Comment: do you really need release all memory when you leave that activity?

Comment: Yes, all memory have to release to ready at next application execute.
I need to **Close Application and Release Memory** at activity destroy.

Comment: I don't know why you have to release to ready next application execute. your application memory will be released by system when it need. for static variables?

Comment: All memory need to released cause of high memory usage (like data) in this application.
If system not release application, can cause of huge memory leak.

Other application is closing after backpressed, but it is not closing after mainactivity ended.

Comment: if high memory isn't caused by static variables, it would be garbage collected

Comment: Okay, I understood. Thanks, Choim!

Comment: ** I decided to force-exit application to close them.  Don't want to have any memory leak at my application.
Do not follow this resolution if you using multi thread application.